# do I need to store all the data of screens I've navigated to state in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, store

facebook or instagram for example,
there's user page that contains the owner's posts.

when I visit user1's page and store the posts in state,
I'll have user1's posts in my state.

and if I move to user2's page and update posts state,
the posts will be replaced.

in this case,
should I send request again to get user1's posts when I call navigate.goBack() to see user1's page again?

generally we don't send request again when we go back to previous route.
or is there something like "history" for state?

Answer (score 1):

There's no 'history' for state like the kind you're describing. If you wanted to save a user's posts so you can access it later, you would have to ***expand your state shape*** to store posts from multiple users.

You can check out this section of the `redux` doc for some more insights on how to do this:
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

The gist of it is to make your state into a database.

Comment: Great! Hope my answer was helpful